# MySQL - Get next closest day between two days

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, sql-limit

We have two dates in database:

1. 2013-08-01
2. 2013-08-03

Let say that today's date is 2013-08-02 and we want to get next closest date from database. I've found this query, but it's not getting the next day but previous:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  your_table 
ORDER BY 
  ABS(DATEDIFF(NOW(), `date`))
LIMIT 1
```

When we run it, we get 2013-08-01 and not 2013-08-03 as we want. What would be the solution?

Comment: Do you always want to get dates in the future or do you want to get the closest date before or after the current date?

Comment: The two dates are equidistant.  How did you determine that 2013-08-03 was preferred over 2013-08-01?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Others have already posted the answer if you always want a future date:

```
select *
from your_table
where date > now()
order by date 
limit 1
```

If there is no future date and you still want to return the last date, then you can do this by modifying the `order by` clause:

```
select *
from your_table
order by (date > now()) desc,
         (case when date > now() then date end) ,
         date desc
limit 1;
```

EDIT (in response to comment):

To handle "today" as the closest date, you need to convert `now()` to a date and use `>=`:

```
select *
from your_table
order by (`date` >= date(now())) desc,
         (case when `date` >= date(now()) then `date` end) ,
         `date` desc
limit 1;
```

The `order by` clause has three components.  The first is a flag for any future date.  This puts future dates first.  The second two clauses order by date.  The first orders the future dates in ascending order.   The past dates all have the same value (`'NULL'`), so these are affected by the third clause which orders them in descending order.

Comment: The second query is almost good, but what if there is also date which is pointing on today?

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you please just add some comments to "order by", because it's first time when I'm seeing query with more "order by" subqueries, especially with case which is something new to me.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT   *
FROM     your_table
WHERE    date >= CURRENT_DATE
ORDER BY date
LIMIT    1
```

Comment: I think OP wants only the future date if there is no closer past date.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date > NOW() ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 1;
```

You will get the next closest date

Comment: but what if there is currently not any date in the future, only for past?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM your_table
ORDER BY 
  MIN(DATEDIFF(NOW(), `date`)) ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Will give you the higher one, cause for future date it will be -1, then 1,2,..., so sort them by ASC and without ABS, but not sure it will be good for all your situations.

Comment: with this one I only get the lasest date, but not next one of current

Comment: try with `MIN(DATEDIFF(NOW(), date) ASC)`

Answer (score 0):

it must be there a condition `where` over the date for giving only next dates and not the previous ones

Comment: Please provide an example. Thanks!

Comment: suppose we have these values:<br/>
01-01-2013<br/>
03-01-2013<br/>
05-01-2013<br/>

and the NOW() function returns 02-01-2013<br/>
with the where condition it returns 03-01-20 <br/>